# React native Drag Drop

Tags: react-native, drag-and-drop

How to drag elements on top of other elements?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiaLG.png)

It is necessary to implement dragging orders from above onto cells. I tried several options, but they failed:

1. The top component occupies the entire screen area and is absolute, faced with the fact that when dragging the order is under the cells.
   If orders are displayed after the cells, then the entire screen becomes inactive, since the entire component is covered by orders
2. I implemented a separate component that will be dragged during a long press order, but I was faced with the fact that I don’t know how to pass the click event from the order component to the dragged component